# How to make null values at the end of sorting in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Iv'e been trying to find ways to sort documents in mongodb so that null values 
will always be last
for a smart pagination i'm using

anyone how it can be done with mongoose ?

```
var query = Product.find({}).sort({
    price: sortOrder,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate, and make a temporary field (isNull) to check if the `sortOrder` is null. Then you only have to sort by `{ $sort: { isNull: -1, sortOrder: 1 }}`

```
var query = Product.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            ...
            sortOrder: '$sortOrder',
            isNull: { $toBool: { $ifNull: [ '$posts.pageOrder', 0 ] } },
        }
    },
    { $sort: { isNull: -1, pageOrder: 1 } }
])
```

in different case when you want to sort null at the end by the update_at (new -> old), you can use it like this:

```
var query = Product.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            ...
            sortOrder: '$sortOrder',
            isNull: { $toBool: { $ifNull: [ '$posts.pageOrder', 0 ] } },
            updated_at: '$updated_at'
        }
    },
    { $sort: { isNull: -1, pageOrder: 1, updated_at: -1 } }
])
```